# Gather arbitrary data in feeds xpathparser without mapping it to a field?

Tags: feeds

I gather data with the feeds module and xpathparser.

Sample data 1:

```
<xml>
  <id>1234</id>
</xml>
```

Sample data 2:

```
<xml>
  <id>1235</id>
  <ref-id>1234</ref-id>
  <action>delete</action>
</xml>
```

In the incoming XML data, there are two fields, used to signify an old entry should be deleted. In my feeds `Parser->parse()`, I have

```
$this->config['sources']['refid'] = 'XML/ref-id';
$this->config['sources']['action'] = 'XML/action';
```

which makes the parser get these two data values even if I don't map them to a field. But I can find no way of making this information available to the Processor. I would like to find some way of sticking this data on to the $node, so that in entitySave() I can ignore saving id 1235 and instead delete 1234.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this issue: [Map "Temporary target" to a property of an entity](http://drupal.org/node/1536736), [Feeds tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) seems to be the way to do this.